# "For each" loop for two object

Tags: java, for-loop

```
ArrayList<String> date=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> time=new ArrayList<String>();
//addition of elements in the list
...
...
for(String x :date,String y: time)
{
    System.out.println(x+" "+y);
}
```

Is two objects can be iterate by single "for  each" loop?
i tried above code,i got compilation error. Is any syntax mistake is there?

Comment: it doesn't work this way

Comment: No, you cannot iterate this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, this isn't going to work.  There is no way to do this with a for-each loop; you will have to do a normal for loop with either explicit indices or with iterators.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality, but there are [third-party libraries](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) and freely available code for Java-8 that let you do this:

```
Stream<String> a = Stream.of(date);
Stream<String> b = Stream.of(time);

List<String> zip = StreamUtils.zip(a, b,
                                  (a, b) -> a + " " + b)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are not using Java 8 or are not comfortable using streams, using a `for` loop with an index or iterating two iterators is the next closest thing:

```
Iterator<String> a = date.iterator();
Iterator<String> b = time.iterator();
while (a.hasNext() && b.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(a.next() + " " + b.next());
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/WiwE5C)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs,i just want to know whether Language is ability to do this feature and i got the answer for that. Anyway i remember your's too